# Flipping the x & y axis in diagram resulting from plot_simultaneous() in a Tukey HSD test

Tags: python, statsmodels, tukey

I have a data set and I need to check significant differences between 5 groups. The resulting diagram shows test groups on the y-axis and the response on the x-axis. However I want the figure to show the reverse, that is response on the y-axis and test groups on the x-axis. So the confidence interval bars should be vertical as opposed to the horizontal shown below. How can this be achieved?

Here is a fully reproducible sample of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import MultiComparison
from statsmodels.stats.multicomp import pairwise_tukeyhsd

response = [4,5, 7,6, 2,3, 12,9, 7,7]
groups = ["test1","test1","test2","test2","test3","test3","test4","test4","test5","test5"]

result = pairwise_tukeyhsd(response, groups, alpha=0.05)

# Plot the results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1, 1))

# Customize the plot appearance
result.plot_simultaneous(
    comparison_name='test3',
    ax = ax,
    figsize = (8,5),
    xlabel = "Response",     # X-axis label
    ylabel = 'Test Group',   # Y-axis label
)

# Reverse the order of labels on the y-axis
ax.invert_yaxis()

# Add a title to the plot
ax.set_title(f'Tukey\'s HSD Test for Response')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a solution except rewriting the plot function and swapping `x` and `y` https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/sandbox/stats/multicomp.py#L668 (If someone does that, then it could be added as option to statsmodels. That method was written a long time ago, there might be a more efficient way of plotting it after collecting the relevant data from TukeyHSDResults.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. However there is no x and y there, only 'self'. What should be changed?

Comment: All the matplotlib plot commands need to flip x and y arguments, Those are the first two arguments in plot methods and e.g. `ax1.errorbar` needs to use `yerr` instead of `xerr` keyword.